# SPFx web part similar to the Quick Links web part which check if the user have permission on the related links (internal and external links)

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint, spfx

I am working on a project to build a portal inside SharePoint online. Now i got this requirement:-

- To build a quick links web part in React SPFx (similar to the built-in modern Quick Links)
- But this quick links can contain links to internal applications that can only be accessed using VPN.
- So if the user access the SharePoint online home page without VPN >> the quick links should hide all the links which the user does not have access to.
- Also if the user access the SharePoint using VPN and the user does not have permission to the internal system (the user will get http 401 or will be prompted with a dialog to enter username and password) to hide the links as well.

So in other words, the SPFx web part need to send a request to the link url, and if it get http code other than "2xx success" to hide the link.

Can anyone advice how to build such a web part please?

Now i tried to benefit from this SPFx web part @ https://github.com/clarktozer/spfx-quicklinks . where this is the `QuickLinksWebPart.ts`:-

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import { Version } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';
import {
  BaseClientSideWebPart,
  IPropertyPaneConfiguration,
  PropertyPaneDropdown,
  PropertyPaneCheckbox} from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base';

import * as strings from 'QuickLinksWebPartStrings';
import QuickLinks from './components/QuickLinks';
import { IQuickLinksProps } from './components/IQuickLinksProps';
import { PropertyPaneLinksList } from '../../controls/PropertyPaneLinksList/PropertyPaneLinksList';
import { PropertyFieldColorPicker, PropertyFieldColorPickerStyle } from '@pnp/spfx-property-controls/lib/PropertyFieldColorPicker';
import { Link } from '../../controls/PropertyPaneLinksList/components/ILinksListState';

export interface IQuickLinksWebPartProps {
  title: string;
  type: LinkType;
  iconColor: string;
  openInNewTab?: boolean;
  fontColor: string;
  initLinks: string[];
  links: Link[];
}

export enum LinkType {
  LINK = "Link",
  FILE = "File"
}
export default class QuickLinksWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IQuickLinksWebPartProps> {

  public render(): void {
    const element: React.ReactElement<IQuickLinksProps> = React.createElement(
      QuickLinks,
      {
        title: this.properties.title,
        type: this.properties.type,
        iconColor: this.properties.iconColor,
        fontColor: this.properties.fontColor,
        openInNewTab: this.properties.openInNewTab,
        links: this.properties.links != null ? this.properties.links : [],
        displayMode: this.displayMode,
        updateProperty: (value: string) => {
          this.properties.title = value;
        }
      }
    );

    ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
  }

  protected onDispose(): void {
    ReactDom.unmountComponentAtNode(this.domElement);
  }

  protected get dataVersion(): Version {
    return Version.parse('1.0');
  }

  protected getPropertyPaneConfiguration(): IPropertyPaneConfiguration {
    return {
      pages: [
        {
          header: {
            description: strings.PropertyPaneDescription
          },
          groups: [
            {
              groupName: strings.BasicGroupName,
              groupFields: [
                PropertyPaneDropdown('type', {
                  label: strings.LinkType,
                  options: Object.keys(LinkType).map((e) => {
                    return {
                      key: LinkType[e], text: LinkType[e]
                    };
                  }),
                  selectedKey: 'link'
                }),
                PropertyPaneCheckbox('openInNewTab', {
                  text: strings.OpenInNewTab
                })
              ]
            },
            {
              groupName: strings.StylingGroup,
              groupFields: [
                PropertyFieldColorPicker('iconColor', {
                  label: strings.IconColor,
                  selectedColor: this.properties.iconColor,
                  onPropertyChange: this.onPropertyPaneFieldChanged.bind(this),
                  properties: this.properties,
                  disabled: false,
                  alphaSliderHidden: false,
                  style: PropertyFieldColorPickerStyle.Inline,
                  key: 'iconColor'
                }),
                PropertyFieldColorPicker('fontColor', {
                  label: strings.FontColor,
                  selectedColor: this.properties.fontColor,
                  onPropertyChange: this.onPropertyPaneFieldChanged.bind(this),
                  properties: this.properties,
                  disabled: false,
                  alphaSliderHidden: false,
                  style: PropertyFieldColorPickerStyle.Inline,
                  key: 'fontColor'
                })
              ]
            },
            {
              groupName: strings.LinksGroup,
              groupFields: [
                new PropertyPaneLinksList("links", {
                  key: "links",
                  links: this.properties.links
                })
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

and this is the `QuikcLinks.tsx` :-

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styles from './QuickLinks.module.scss';
import { IQuickLinksProps } from './IQuickLinksProps';
import { autobind } from '@uifabric/utilities';
import { LinkType } from '../QuickLinksWebPart';
import { WebPartTitle } from "@pnp/spfx-controls-react/lib/WebPartTitle";
import Radium from 'radium';
import * as tinycolor from 'tinycolor2';

@Radium
export default class QuickLinks extends React.Component<IQuickLinksProps, {}> {
  private inlineStyles: any;
  constructor(props: IQuickLinksProps) {
    super(props);
  }

  @autobind
  private createLinkStyle(hoverColor) {
    return {
      color: this.props.fontColor,
      ':hover': {
        color: tinycolor(hoverColor).darken(25).toString()
      }
    };
  }

  @autobind
  public getIcon() {
    let icon = "";
    switch (this.props.type) {
      case LinkType.FILE:
        icon = "OpenFile";
        break;
      default:
        icon = "Link";
    }
    return icon;
  }

  public render(): React.ReactElement<IQuickLinksProps> {
    this.inlineStyles = {
      link: this.createLinkStyle(this.props.fontColor)
    };
    return (
      <div className={"ms-Grid " + styles.quickLinks}>
        <div>
          <div className="ms-Grid-row">
            <div className="ms-Grid-col ms-sm12">
              <WebPartTitle displayMode={this.props.displayMode}
                title={this.props.title}
                updateProperty={this.props.updateProperty} />
              {
                this.props.links.map((e, i) => {
                  let linkProps = {
                    key: e.key,
                    href: e.value
                  };
                  if (this.props.openInNewTab) {
                    linkProps["target"] = "_blank";
                  }
                  return <div className={styles.linkRow} key={this.props.type + "-link-" + i}>
                    <i style={{ color: this.props.iconColor }} className={styles.quickLinkIcon + " ms-Icon ms-Icon--" + this.getIcon()} aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <a className={styles.link} {...linkProps} style={this.inlineStyles.link}>{e.label}</a>
                  </div>;
                })
              }
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

So where i need to do the call to the URL and check the response so i can render the link or hide it accordingly??
Thanks

Comment: AFAIK, this may not possible client-side only (i.e. in the browser) due to CORS. Your script will probably always get CORS error and never 401 or 400. Have you actually tried to do fetch() using javascript to any of your VPN URLs using javascript? You may need a server-side application for this.

Comment: @Nikolay thanks for the reply. so you think SPfx will not be able to achieve this requirement?

Comment: It depends. I would do a simple experiment first, just call `fetch(<your url>, { credentails: 'include' })` from any javascript file that is hosted on your server (or just from the browser dev tools console). If that works, i.e. it succeeds when VPN is connected and fails when not, then SPFx also should work. I mean, the built-in fetch: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch That is, the potential problem could be not with SPFx but with the approach you have choosen (verify links by checking response codes)